# HTML: Totaling columns

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am taking in the data in from an sql statement and throwing it into a table.

I am trying to create a subtotal for the table that I can then send to a checkout page using a java servlet. Problem is that I am having issues getting the subtotal working after going through several examples on stackoverflow.

Thank you for your time.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <script>
        (function (global) {
            document.getElementById("output").value = global.localStorage.getItem("mySharedData");
        }(window));
    </script>
    <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"
                       user="root"  password="nbuser"/>
    <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
        Select F.title, (F.rental_rate * F.rental_duration) as 'Price'
        from cart as C
        join cartofitems as CI
        on CI.cart_id = C.cart_id
        join film as F
        on CI.film_id = F.film_id
    </sql:query>
    <div align="center">
        <table width="850" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFFFFF;" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <img src="images/cart.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="3">
                    <table width="650">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div align="justify" style="color:#3e160e;">
                                    This is a custom HTML header.  This header may contain any HTML code, text,
                                    graphics, active content such as dropdown menus, java, javascript, or other
                                    content that you would like to display at the top of your cart pages.  You create
                                    custom HTML header yourself and specify its location in the CustomCart Administrator.
                                    Also note the custom wallpaper (brown striped background), this is uploaded via the
                                    administrator.  You may change the wallpaper any time you wish to change the look of
                                    your cart.
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div> 
    <div align="center">
        <form action="checkout.jsp" method="post" border="">
            <table width="850" border="1" class="cart">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Movie Title</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var="cart">
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="CartServlet?action=delete&orderNum=<c:out value="${product.orderNum}"/>">Delete</a></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${cart.title}" /></td>
                            <td class="price"><c:out value="${cart.Price}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <tr class="totalColumn">
                        <td  colspan="2" align="right" ><b>Subtotal: </b></td>
                        <td  align="right" ><b><span id="subtotal"></span></b></td>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    var tds = document.getElementById('cart').getElementsByTagName('td');
                    var sum = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
                        if (tds[i].className == 'price') {
                            sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
                        }
                    }
                    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>';
                </script>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table width="850" border="1">
                <tr>
                <div style="width:650px;">

                    <button type="submit" name="your_name" value="totalCost" class="loginbtn">Checkout Cart</button>
                    </form>
                    <p><form action="faces/index.xhtml" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" name="your_name" value="your_value" class="adminloginbtn">Back To Search</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: Where is the element with id price? You should post a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a runnable snippet and replace the server code with plain HTML as if this was in a client page.

Comment: <td class="price">
          <c:out value="${cart.Price}" /> 
uses the for each to load the numbers into the table from sql. I assumed that I could use those columns total them then throw that in the subtotal field.

I may have misunderstood.

Comment: You need to provide a **minimal** example, so just the HTML received by the client reduced to just the parts that are required to show the issue. Also, whatever you do on the client is just for user convenience, it's totally unreliable. You should do all "real" calculations at the server.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I ended up doing the calculation in sql and filling in the subtotal that way. thank you for your help.